# Questions on normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I'm trying to do these and I'm a bit stuck on (a).

I know that $a \in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ so $aH = Ha \in G$.

Notice that from this we can deduce that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. I'm still having problems showing that $ab^{-1} \in H$.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "Notice that from..." . This is wrong. What is true is that *always* $\;H\lhd N_G(H)=:N(H)\;$

Comment: The line before "Notice..." is also wrong. $\;aH=Ha\;\;\forall\,a\in G\iff H\lhd G\;$

Comment: :(               .....................

Answer (score 1):

For (a), let $g,h$ be elements of $N(H)$. Then we check $gh^{-1}\in N(H):$ $$(gh^{-1})H(hg^{-1})=gHg^{-1}=H$$ I'm having trouble parsing the rest of your question. I guess you're trying to outline your proofs of the other parts, but I don't see why you're trying to prove $ab^{-1}\in H$ in any case: we are either taking $H$ an arbitrary subset of $G$ or assuming it's a subgroup, but never need to show that it's a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, however, why do you say that $(gh^{-1})H(hg^{-1})=gHg^{-1}$
I can't seem to get it to fit.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $(gh^{-1}) = a$ and $(hg^{-1}) = a^{-1}$?

Comment: Suppose $h \in N(H)$. By definition this means $hHh^{-1} = H$. Taking inverses of both sides, we have $(hHh^{-1})^{-1} = H^{-1} = H$. But the set $(hHh^{-1})^{-1} = h^{-1}H^{-1}h = h^{-1}Hh$. Thus: $(gh^{-1})H(gh^{-1})^{-1} = (gh^{-1})H(hg^{-1}) = g(h^{-1}Hh)g^{-1} = gHg^{-1} = H$

Comment: Great, thank you. What does it mean for a group to be normal IN another group? Like in b)? I'm a bit stuck on this 'in' part.

Comment: It just means to be a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to do these and I'm a bit stuck on $\rm(a)$.
>
> I know that $a \in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ so $aH = Ha \in G$.

For the proof of $\rm (a)$ you don't know that $H$ is a subgroup, it is just assumed to be a non-empty subset of $G$. Also $aH \neq Ha$ in general, that's a special property of normal subgroups. While the set $aH$ contains all elements $ah$ for $h\in H$, the set $Ha$ contains all elements $ha$ for $h\in H$, these sets need not to be equal and neither of the sets is an element of $G$, so "$Ha\in G$" is wrong, but "$Ha\subseteq G$" is true!

> Notice that from this we can deduce that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. I'm still having problems showing that $ab^{-1} \in H$.

You don't need to show $ab^{-1}\in H$. You need to show that $N(H)$ is a subgroup, not $H$ itself. So for $\rm(a)$ you need to prove

1. $N(H)$ is non-empty.
2. For $g,h\in N(H)$ it holds that $gh^{-1}\in N(H)$.

Comment: Thank you! For b)..What does it mean for a group $H$ to be normal **IN** $G$? The 'in' is confusing me.

Comment: @user3200098 It means $H$ is normal as a subgroup of $G$, *i.e.* $gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g\in G$. A subgroup can be normal in a bigger subgroup while not being normal in the whole group. In $\rm (c)$ you have to show $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in N(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the concept of [group action on a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) you should recognize $N(H)$ to be the stabilizer of the subset $H\subset G$ under the action of $G$ on its own subsets by conjugation.

As such, it is a subgroup because all stabilizers are.